# In postgres Updates 0 rows for matching record

Tags: postgresql

We were trying to update a record in our database as below and the row was not getting updated. No error was shown neither on the command promt nor in the logs

STEP 1:

```
SELECT yrd_cuttoff FROM yrd_yield_room_details WHERE yrd_yrd_key=1491;  
yrd_cuttoff
________________
 N
(1 row)
```

STEP 2:

```
UPDATE yrd_yield_room_details SET yrd_cuttoff='NC' WHERE yrd_yrd_key=1491; 

UPDATE 0
```

STEP 3:

```
SELECT yrd_cuttoff FROM yrd_yield_room_details WHERE yrd_yrd_key=1491;  

yrd_cuttoff
________________
 N
(1 row)
```

Comment: provide table schema here also

Comment: which type of data is yrd_cuttoff ?

Comment: Are there triggers or rules for this table in the database? Did you try to update other columns, what happening in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is no rules on this table. See [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/view-pg-rules.html) and [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createrule.html).